# Diagnosis my fog effect

Tags: modeling, materials, 3d-view

[image]

I saw this on Reddit, and I've tried this in the world and even as an object material. I've never been able to make fog effect this way. I don't know if it's my computer because I copied this picture and I still can't get it to work. Sadly right now all I have is a MacBook Pro with 2.2ghz quad-core Intel Core i7, 16gb ram, graphic: intel iris pro 1536mb.

Now when I try to recreate this. I applied the same node to the volume of the ball and to the world. As you can see, the ball is black and that's all I've ever seen when I've tried it.

Here is the blend file to see if it works on your computer or if something else is not set right: [image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can't be sure, but I think it might be your PC (or setup). When I download your file, I can see the volume just fine (in rendered preview mode).

Comment: Wow! Thanks, so you didn't change a thing, and it just worked fine. Thank you so much